# Android studio kotlin retrofit POST request get response

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So, my app is communicating with my NestJS api with Retrofit, but when i want to use the response, it looks like this:

```
UserModelIn(
    usernameError="error",
    passwordError="error",
    ok=false,
)
```

Can you tell me why? Thanks!

**Heres my code:**

**Dataclasses:**

```
data class UserModelOut(
    val username: String,
    val password: String,
)

data class UserModelIn(
    val usernameError: String,
    val passwordError: String,
    val ok: Boolean,
)
```

**Interface:**

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("test")
    fun sendReq(@Body requestModel: RqsModel) : Call<ResModel>

    @POST("register")
    fun register(@Body registerModelOut: UserModelOut): Call<UserModelIn>
}
```

**ServiceBuilder:**

```
            val response = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
            response.register(UserModelOut("", "")).enqueue(
                object : Callback<UserModelIn> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<UserModelIn>,
                        response: Response<UserModelIn>
                    ) {
                        usernameError.text = response.body().toString()
                       // var response = response.body().toString().trim();
                        //textView.text = response.message().toString()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModelIn>, t: Throwable) {
                       // textView.text = t.toString()
                    }

                }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
            val response = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
            response.register(UserModelOut("", "")).enqueue(
                object : Callback<UserModelIn> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<UserModelIn>,
                        response: Response<UserModelIn>
                    ) {


                       // get for example the usernameError:
                        usernameError.text = response.body()?.usernameError
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModelIn>, t: Throwable) {
                       // textView.text = t.toString()
                    }

                }
            )
```